# Value changes in a struct when editing another struct in another function

Tags: c, struct

I've run into a problem with structs which I believe is caused by incorrect mallocs, or possibly rather my reallocs. I've cut down the code as much as possible to only show what I believe could be relevant, so nearly all the actual operations are omitted.

The struct I have looks as follows:

```
struct poly_t {
    int nvars, *factor, *exp;
};
```

The value that's acting weird is `nvars`, which to me would signify that I'm somehow not reserving memory properly. What I do is that I first have a function that creates and fills the struct, then I have another function where I send two of these structs in and create a third identical struct. When editing the value of nvars in this third struct, it very rarely also edits the value of nvars in the first struct. When running gdb, it shows the exact row it happens on is when I do `thirdp->nvars++;` in my mul function.

So with this function I create my first and second structs (`a` and `b`).

```
poly_t* new_poly_from_string(const char* a){
    struct poly_t* p = malloc(sizeof(struct poly_t));
    p->nvars = 0;
    p->factor = malloc(strlen(a) * sizeof(int));
    p->exp = malloc(strlen(a) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
        //do stuff to put a into p, using at most p->factor[p->nvars] and the same for p->exp
    p->factor = realloc(p->factor, p->nvars*sizeof(int));
    p->exp = realloc(p->exp, p->nvars*sizeof(int));
    printf("%d", p->nvars); //At this point, nvars is the correct value
    return p;
}
```

And below is the function that works in 9/10 cases but in some rare cases it doesn't. I've marked the exact row that changes `a->nvars` with an arrow `-->`.

```
poly_t* mul(poly_t* a, poly_t* b){
    struct poly_t* thirdp = malloc(sizeof(struct poly_t));
    thirdp->nvars = 0;
    thirdp->factor = malloc((a->nvars + b->nvars) * sizeof(int));
    thirdp->exp = malloc((a->nvars + b->nvars) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < a->nvars; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < b->nvars; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < p->nvars; k++){
                if (p->exp[k] == a->exp[i] + b->exp[j]){
                    p->factor[k] += a->factor[i]*b->factor[j];
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found){
                p->factor[p->nvars] = a->factor[i]*b->factor[j];
                p->exp[p->nvars] = a->exp[i] + b->exp[j];
-->             p->nvars++; //This is the row that changes a->nvars according to gdb
            }
        }
    }

    return thirdp;
}
```

Here's what I got when running gdb while trying to figure out what was changing `a->nvars`. Note that `p` is the same as `thirdp` above, I just renamed it here for clarity.

[image: GDB output]

edit: Readded the actual code in the mul function

Comment: Are you sure `a->nvars` is at its correct value when you enter in the function `mul`? If yes, it is probably the "fill thirdp->factor and thirdp->exp" that changes it.

Comment: Yes, the gdb debug shows that it is, and it shows that it changes at `p->nvars++`, not in the `//fill` part, oddly enough.

Comment: `thirdp` == `p` inside `mul`? If not, where does `p` come from?

Comment: Ugh, forgot to rename it when I edited the rest of the code in. Anyway, got it solved now, will add an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as I believed in the `mallocs`. Specifically the following two rows:

```
thirdp->factor = malloc((a->nvars + b->nvars) * sizeof(int));
thirdp->exp = malloc((a->nvars + b->nvars) * sizeof(int));
```

I simply wasn't allocating enough memory which caused the weird behaviour. What I wanted was:

```
thirdp->factor = malloc((a->exp[0] + b->exp[0]) * sizeof(int));
thirdp->exp = malloc((a->exp[0] + b->exp[0]) * sizeof(int));
```

Unfortunately since I didn't give any of the indata, or really much context, you guys probably couldn't have figured that out <.< Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating space for the sum of the number of integers

```
 a->nvars + b->nvars
```

I wonder what you do in

```
//fill thirdp->factor and thirdp->exp
```

As you have nested for loops I suspect you may be generating

```
  a->nvars * b->nvars  //multiply
```

items and hence running off the end of allocated space. You now show us the code and we see

```
    if (!found){
        // --- here ----
        p->factor[p->nvars] = a->factor[i]*b->factor[j];
        p->exp[p->nvars] = a->exp[i] + b->exp[j];
        p->nvars++;
    }
```

At the point I mark *here* you should check the value of p->nvars, I think it has the possibility to reach a value greater than (a->nvars + b->nvars).

I think to be safe allocate the space for (a->nvars * b->nvars) ints.

Comment: Adding an edit to my original post to include exactly what I do there.

Comment: I see now how really bad my edit was, sorry! p->nvars++ isn't run every iteration of the loop, only sometimes.

Comment: But it the limiting case it might be? It has the potential to be run depending on the details of the earlier algorithm, whenever !found. It's good defensive programming to put the check in, can do no harm and might catch the unexpected. Strongly suggest you add the check, if it catches nothing then we've eliminated one possible cause.